# in Windows Command Line Prompt, why do my python files open in vim instead of executing?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vim, windows-explorer

I seem to have edited some setting for windows command prompt in windows 7 and forgot.
[EDIT: it was just set as the default application for .py files in windows explorer. Dennis answered it below]

(sidenote: what is the correct way to refer to this prompt? should I call it wondows command prompt? cmd.exe? cmd? ms-dos? dos?)

whenever I enter the path to a python file, it opens that file in an editor (vim) instead of executing it. Where can you edit default actions for filetypes? Why can't I execute a .py file? why does it open an editor instead of executing the file?

Thanks!

Comment: "Windows command prompt" is correct. You can also use "cmd prompt". If you use "ms-dos" or "dos" you're likely to hear objections since it's not technically DOS (however, it quacks and walks a lot like DOS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
assoc | findstr "\.py"
```

You should get the following results:

```
.py=Python.File
.pyc=Python.CompiledFile
.pyo=Python.CompiledFile
.pyw=Python.NoConFile
```

and

```
ftype | findstr "Python"
```

should give you:

```
Python.CompiledFile="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.NoConFile="C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

If any of those are missing, commands such as the following examples should fix them:

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Also, in Windows Explorer, right click on a `.py` file and select `Open with...` and see if it says `python.exe` or `vim.exe`. If it's wrong, you should be able to change it there.

Comment: thank you. I tried it and these all returned the expected results - nothing was missing.

Comment: Pipe both `assoc` and `ftype` through `findstr "vim"` to see if anything unusual shows up. Also, in Windows Explorer, right click on a `.py` file and select `Open with...` and see if it says `python.exe` or `vim.exe`. If it's wrong, you should be able to change it there.

Comment: can you repost the windows explorer suggestion as an answer so I can give it a big fat green check mark?

Comment: @Benjamin: Done.